# MySQL copy based on conditions

Tags: mysql, database, copy

I have 2 tables. Table 1 (content_id, prop_name, content plus other empty fields I can drop locally) from a cms and table 2 (meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value) created with WordPress and advanced custom fields. I want to copy over 'content' table 1 to 'meta_value' table 2.

Of course the correct ones copying over to correct places in table 2. When content_id = post_id and prop_name = meta_key are same take content and copy to corresponding meta_value. This is a one time job with several prop_name/meta_key in 1000s of rows.

Uploaded two images to imgur to illustrate **sorry for the mismatch of the ids in the images, they are just example screenshots**

Table 1
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjBAB.png

Table 2
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pocbW.png

Just as info: The types are int(11), bigint(20) for id and post_id, varchar(255) for both prop_name and meta_key and mediumtext and longtext for  text values.

Not sure how to search for this ('copy mysql' and variations don't seem specific to my question or I am not searching using right terms)

TIA

**EDIT:**

Before:

Table 1 (content_id, prop_name, content) 
16, memberg, lots of text

Table 2 (meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
1, 16, membersg, NULL

After:

Table 2 (meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
1, 16, membersg,  lots of text

Repeated 1000s of rows, based on matching 16, membersg; 16, membersb; 17, membersg, 17 membersb, and others like it

Comment: Really having a hard time figuring out what those images even mean. Also try not to use off-site hosting.

Comment: Sorry about the offsite images, I am not sure I can correct that now(?) Those are two tables, screenshots of few rows of each (as seen in phpmyadmin) Copy the text (shown by arrow) from one table to another.

Comment: Unless you're talking about a design issue, such as a CSS problem, screenshots are almost always the wrong way to describe your requirements. Instead, describe the schema of your table and the operation you're trying to perform. An example of a better approach: Show the rows you're trying to manipulate as text.

Comment: Edited my question above